# Eliminate shift/reduce conflicts caused by production rules with same prefix

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

Here is the simplified yaac file:

```
%token CONTEXT_    // the corresponding string is "context"
%token CONTEXTREF_ //"contextref"
%token IS_         //"is"
%token ID_L        //"id_l"
%token ID_L1       //"id_l1"
%token LIB_

%start design_file

%%
design_file   :design_unit
              |design_file design_unit 
              ;

design_unit   :context_cl LIB_
              |context_decl
              ;

context_cl    : /* empty */  {  }
              |context_cl context_ref
              ;

context_decl  :CONTEXT_ ID_L IS_ ';'
              ;

context_ref   :CONTEXT_ ID_L1 '.' ID_L ';'
              ;
```

There are 2 shift/reduce conflicts.

> ```
> CONTEXT_  shift, and go to state 1
>
> CONTEXT_  [reduce using rule 5 (context_cl)]
> ```

Rule 5 is `context_cl    : /* empty */  {  }`.

Generally, this doesn't matter, the parser works well most of the time.
But in one strange case, for a source file like following:

```
context id_l is ...
...
```

The parser will not shift but reduce, hence using `context_ref   :CONTEXT_ ID_L1 '.' ID_L ';'` to parse `context id_l is ...`, which causes syntax errors.

So I have to eliminate the conflicts.
I guess they are caused by rule `context_decl` and `context_ref` both having `CONTEXT_`  in the beginning.

To validate my guess, I just changed `context_ref   :CONTEXT_ ID_L1 '.' ID_L ';'` to `context_ref   :CONTEXTREF_ ID_L1 '.' ID_L ';'`. Then, there is no conflict and there is no syntax error.

However, I can't replace `context_ref` this way. This is the standard.

So, how can I avoid these 2 conflicts by other means? Or, is there a general method to tackle conflicts of this kind?

And, for shift/reduce conflicts, will the parser choose to reduce rather than shift? Because I think the parser will always shift over reduce.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you describe. I used exactly the grammar you specify and got precisely the shift/reduce conflict you quote, in two states. So that all checks out. I guessed what a lexer might look like and ran it with the input `context id_l is ;` in debug mode; it recognized the input without error. It won't parse `context id_l1 ...` because of the resolution of the shift/reduce conflict. Is that what you meant? If so, please edit your question and I'll try to answer it. Otherwise, a [mcve], please, with an emphasis on "complete" and "verifiable".

Comment: The syntax errors occurred  intermittently. So I just want to eliminate shift/reduce conflicts.@rici

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic pattern which gives rise to this conflict is:

```
union : x x_rest
      | y_list y_rest
y_list: /* empty */
      | y_list y
```

where `x` and `y` both have a production starting with the same symbol.

It's worth noting that the problem will vanish if `y_list` is one-or-more `y`s, instead of zero or more:

```
y_list: y
      | y_list y
```

as long as `x` and `y` are really distinguishable. (There are some other requirements, depending on the rest of the production, but basically it's OK if they have the same prefix. They could even be the same provided that the continuations differ in the first token.)

If you really need `y_list` to be potentially empty (or both `x` and `y` to be potentially empty), you should do the usual null-production elimination, which involves factoring the potentially empty production out of the grammar:

```
union : x x_rest
      | y_rest           /* Corresponds to an empty y_list */
      | y_list y_rest
y_list: y                /* As above, this list cannot be empty */
      | y_list y
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where your "intermittent" syntax errors are coming from -- as written your grammar can never match an input like `context id_l1 . id_l` ... as the shift will cause it to try to parse `context_decl` not a `context_ref`.

That said, however, your conflict has little to do with the common prefixes -- its really coming from the `/* empty */`, and the easiest fix is to refactor it to remove that rule:

```
design_unit   : context_cl LIB_
              | LIB_
              | context_decl
              ;

context_cl    : context_ref
              | context_cl context_ref
              ;
```

So now `context_cl` is "1 or more" `context_ref`s instead of "0 or more", and we've duplicated the `design_unit` rule to have the 0 case separately.